# Why doesn't my sales tax calculator work?

Tags: ruby

```
puts "Hello, welcome to the sales tax calculator"
puts "What is your total price?"
price = gets.chomp
tax = 0.0635 * price
total = tax + price
puts "#{total} is your price including sales tax"
```

It should take the price and add the sales tax. Sorry, Ruby noob.

Comment: Update the question with error

Comment: What isn't working as expected?

Comment: Please be more specific as to the error your getting.  Make sure gets.chomp has a value

Answer (score 1):

When you enter in a value from your prompt, it will come in as a String.  You'll want to convert it to a float using [`String#to_f`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-to_f).

For instance:

```
price = gets.to_f
```

If you gave the prompt 10.0 it would convert it like this:

```
[16] pry(main)> "10.0\n".to_f
=> 10.0
```

chomp doesn't appear necessary for this, simply calling `to_f` is removing the newline character which is something I just learned!